# Nesting AngularJS Directives That Require Communication?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can I nest two of the same directives that require communication with the parent (AngularJS Docs: [Creating Directive that Communicate](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate))?

I am attempting to implement an AngularJS solution to Bootstrap's ScrollSpy.  I have successfully done so ([my gist](https://gist.github.com/EvilClosetMonkey/9194765)) using Alexander Hill's [Using AngularJS to recreate Bootstrap's ScrollSpy](http://alxhill.com/blog/articles/angular-scrollspy/) as my primary reference.

A simplified HTML looks like this (nothing out of the norm for directives that require a parent directive):

```
<div parent-directive>
  <!-- content -->

  <div child-directive="foo">...</div>
  <div child-directive="bar">...</div>

  <!-- more content -->
</div>
```

But when I try to nest the same directive types, everything breaks. For example:

```
<div parent-directive>
  <!-- content -->

  <div child-directive="foo">...</div>
  <div child-directive="bar">...</div>

  <!-- more content -->

  <div parent-directive>
    <div child-directive="snipp">...</div>
    <div child-directive="snapp">...</div>
    <div child-directive="snurr">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My specific goal is to be able to provide two scroll-spy elements within the same page, as [Bootstrap's ScrollSpy documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy) shows.  That is, the documentation is one big ScrollSpy, and then there is an example of a ScrollSpy within that parent.

Am I able to nest two like directives in order to accomplish this?

Comment: did u see any error in console

Comment: Nope. Both directives just don't respond.